Identifying and extracting unknown date time format
I have a dataset with a timestamp in the format :
Out[1]:
 734633.853009
 734633.853011
 734633.853018
 734633.853018
 734633.853019

and so on.
I have looked up various date formats and conversions possible but couldn't find any format that gives sensible dates.
What I know is that the sampling frequency is of 100Hz, and the year of the timestamp should be around 2013-2014.
I would really appreciate any help.
Tested unix dates, epoch format, serial date etc. The dates were always very off (very close to 1970/01/01).

Could be a number of (fractional) seconds from some arbitrary Epoch but unless you know what the Epoch is, you're lost

Thanks for your response, the dataset comes from a GitHub project, though without any explanation for the timestamp format. The original author is not responding, so I am kinda clueless. But thanks for your response.

These could be based on the proleptic Gregorian calendar. If that's the case then the fromordindal method available in the datetime module will help you to decipher the date (the integer part). The fractional part could then be used to determine the time. For example, 734633 could represent 10/05/2012 (DD/MM/YYYY)

It looks like the value units are days.  Since OP hasn't specified what the desired result is, below is an example with a guess at the epoch.  Adjust as needed.  Need samples of the correct answer for a particular value to validate.
import datetime as dt

epoch = 1,1,1 # YMD January 1, 0001 as an example

nums = 734633.853009, 734633.853011, 734633.853018, 734633.853018, 734633.853019
for num in nums:
    print(dt.datetime(*epoch) + dt.timedelta(days=num))

Output:
2012-05-11 20:28:19.977596
2012-05-11 20:28:20.150397
2012-05-11 20:28:20.755202
2012-05-11 20:28:20.755202
2012-05-11 20:28:20.841603


Thanks for your response, the dataset comes from a GitHub project, though without any explanation for the timestamp format. The original author is not responding, so I am kinda clueless. But thanks for your response.
